# Node Cannot GET response

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using LINE login module, I am able to access the oauth page but whenever I click Allow this app to login the response is Cannot/GET views/pages/callbackurl.ejs. This is the code that I run locally

```
  "use strict";

const app = require('express')();
const line_login = require("line-login");

const login = new line_login({
    channel_id: 15818,
    channel_secret: "6bfb55e907",
    callback_url: "http://localhost:5000/views/pages/callbackurl.ejs",
    scope: "openid profile",
    prompt: "consent",
    bot_prompt: "normal"
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening to ${process.env.PORT || 5000}...`);
});

// Specify the path you want to start authorization.
app.use("/", login.auth());

// Specify the path you want to wait for the callback from LINE authorization endpoint.
app.use("http://localhost:5000/views/pages/callbackurl.ejs", login.callback((req, res, next, token_response) => {
    // Success callback
    res.json(token_response);
},(req, res, next, error) => {
    // Failure callback
    res.status(400).json(error);
}));
```

Comment: Please remove `channel_id` and `channel_secret` from this public question, if are valid.

Comment: nope they're not valid. I've edited it already, its not the real id and channel secret

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue, because your callback url is `/views/pages/callbackurl.ejs`. Whenever authentication is successful, `Line` redirects back to `callback_url` mentioned in `LineOptions`, but in your case, you have not implemented `/views/pages/callbackurl.ejs`. It is `/callbackurl`.

So, you can change `callback_url` to `http://localhost:5000/callbackurl` to get valid redirection after successful oauth.

```
const app = require('express')();
const line_login = require("line-login");

const login = new line_login({
   channel_id: 15818,
   channel_secret: "6bfb55e907",
   callback_url: "/callbackurl",  // Update this url on Line developer portal
   scope: "openid profile",
   prompt: "consent",
   bot_prompt: "normal"
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
   console.log(`server is listening to ${process.env.PORT || 5000}...`);
});

// Specify the path you want to start authorization.
app.use("/", login.auth());

// Specify the path you want to wait for the callback from LINE authorization endpoint.
app.use("/callbackurl", login.callback((req, res, next, token_response) => {
   // Success callback
   res.json(token_response);
},(req, res, next, error) => {
   // Failure callback
   res.status(400).json(error);
}));
```

Comment: thank you for the response, im still getting the same error. should I use app.get()?

Comment: `app.use` should be fine, but you can try `app.get`. You must update `callback_url` in code as well as on Line developer portal.

Comment: can you update the latest code in question and error you are getting?

Comment: As we can see you have wrongly mentioned `callback_url` and route.

Comment: hi Mukesh. thank you. redirection works, however I cannot output res.json, in the callback url , the app is deployed in Heroku for live testing.